# How to find the Longest Common Subarray of m arrays each of size n?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

We have a **2D matrix** A of M rows where each row is filled with a permutation of natural numbers from **1** to **N (A[M][N])**

We have to determine the length of the longest common Subarray among all the rows of the matrix

Example :

```
A = {{1,2,3,4},{3,4,1,2},{3,1,2,4}}

Longest common Subarray {1,2}

Length of LCS = 2

Output = 2
```

I don't need the code just a suggestion for optimization.

Comment: Read [tour] and  [ask]. StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service, so you should edit your honest attempt to code this into your question as a [mre].

Comment: Did you try solution below? Did it help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Iterate through each array, let i-th array be `A[i]`
2)Go through each subarray of `A[i]` calculating their hashes and putting them with the 
length of subarray into `map<pair<hashType, int>, int>` counting how many times hash appeared
3)find the hash that appeared n times with the maximum length
if you have any questions on this comment below